# Exporting on-prem SQL Server to Azure SQL using BAPAC fails because of users with Windows Auth

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql

I have an on-prem SQL Server 2014 database - the schema itself is fine and fully Azure SQL compatible.

However, it has a `USER` object that is bound to a Server `LOGIN` which is configured to use Windows Authentication (so passwords aren't stored in connection-strings).

I want to Export this database to Azure SQL, however BACPAC generation fails because of the `USER` object:

> One or more unsupported elements were found in the schema used as part of a data package.
>   Error SQL71564: The element User: `[applicationuser]` has property `AuthenticationType` set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
>   Error SQL71564: The element Login: `[SERVERNAME\LocalUserName]` has property `IsMappedToWindowsLogin` set to a value that is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.

SQL Server Management Studio 2014 does not let me exclude or ignore `USER` and `LOGIN` objects when creating BACPAC files.

SQL Server Data Tools does let me exclude those objects, but SSDT cannot (to my knowledge) perform BACPAC generation, which is my objective.

Comment: Can you go to Security > Logins and delete the username or user group then try again? Once exported to Azure SQL, create a new login from the Azure portal.

Comment: @Peter That would work, but would mean having to stop the production application while the BACPAC generation runs (because the app wouldn't be able to login).

Comment: How about changing the database to mixed mode authentication? Is it possible for the application to use a connection string with a SQL login account instead of SSPI / Windows Authentication? Since this is Azure SQL database, I don't think there should be any reference to the on-prem SQL server.

Comment: This is an insanely frustrating issue. I can't believe they don't include an option to just ignore the damn windows authentication users. They're all IIS APPPOOL users!

Answer (score 2):

I first tried to delete the users which didn't work. Then I found this MS tool which worked perfectly. I was able to migrate both the schema and the data with it without any issues.

MS [Data Migration Assistant](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database) (DMA)